# MYSQL Query Date Between

Tags: mysql, sql

What is wrong with this query

```
select  a.TESTDATE  from testr a,XREFRTGTE b where a.id = b.id and a.TESTDATE between BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2011-05-26 12:22:33','YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS') AND STR_TO_DATE('2011-06-02 12:22:33','YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS') limit 200
```

Please help

Comment: I see two between and I don't know why you're using str_to_date if you have to datetime fields and not strings.

Answer (score 2):

I can see two `between` used in the query:

```
... between BETWEEN ...
```

Try dropping one.